# What parameter does orderer use to order transactions in Hyperledger Fabric v1.0?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

What parameter is used for orderer to order transactions?

1. by timestamp issued in an endorser
2. by sequence number issued in a client or an endorser
3. received by an orderer in a sequential order
4. depends on configuration
5. other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the orderer makes no guarantees about the order in which messages will be delivered just that messages will be delivered in the same order to all peer nodes.

In practice, the following generally holds true for the current orderer implementations:

Solo - messages should be delivered in the order in which they were received

Kafka - messages should be delivered in the order in which they were received by each orderer node and generally even in the order they are received across multiple ordering nodes.

But as mentioned, neither of the above is guaranteed by any ordering implementation

Comment: does this still hold for latest fabric version? Or is it modified?

Comment: still holds true